# Python、replaceを使って特定の列のカンマを削除したい

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで下記の方法で、replaceを使ってcsvのC列のカンマを削除したいですが、
削除されません。

csvデータ

```
A,B,C
Test,America,"13,500"
```

置き換え・削除している方法

```
#C列のカンマを削除
df4['C'].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

C列のdtype

```
print(df4['C'])

Name: C, dtype: object
```

実現したい結果

```
      A        B       C
0  Test  America  13500
```

なぜ削除もしく置き換えされないないか。
分かる方いますでしょうか。
お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

全体のコード

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta

filename=r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\comma.csv"

#当日の日付
strDate = dt.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#CSVを読み込む
with codecs.open(filename, "r", "Shift-JIS", "ignore") as file:
    df1 = pd.read_table(file, delimiter=",")
    print(df1)
    #df1 = pd.read_csv(filename_compare,dtype=str, encoding='utf_8')

    #指定した列名にNaNを含む行を削除
    df2=df1.dropna(subset=["A"]) #https://qiita.com/yuta-38/items/122e607770b88d445d2e
    
    #NaNを含む行を0に置き換え
    df3=df2.fillna(0)

    #日付型の形式を変換
    df4 =df3.replace({'/': '-'}, regex=True)
    
    #C列のカンマを削除
    df4['C'].replace(',', '', regex=True)

    print(df4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純にDataFrameの中身を置き換えていないからでしょう。
この部分を：

```
    #C列のカンマを削除
    df4['C'].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

このようにすれば希望の結果が得られると思います。

```
    #C列のカンマを削除
    df4['C'] = df4['C'].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方ほで問題なくできました。

Answer (score -1):

データフレームのdtypesに各列野方情報が入っているのでそこを見てC列の方を調べてください。多分C列は数値になっておりカンマは便宜上表示されているだけで実際のデータにはありません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。C列のdtype：`object`になります。それでもreplaceしてもカンマ削除されません。